# how to draw double circle nodes in tikz more clear?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I like the drawing final states in Peter Linz's [Book](http://books.google.com/books?id=hsxDiWvVdBcC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), more clear than final states in tikz. can do it with apply an option in tikz, or other packages?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: The book has 433 pages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `double` option in TikZ. The separation distance between the lines can be adjusted using `double distance`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw [double, double distance=1pt] (0,0) circle (14pt);
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey! Two answers based on the same theme! I had been away for dinner, and you had already answered! :) [+1]

Comment: Yeah, I saw this question and thought, "I just did that!"